# set the id of a html element using c# and razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Essentially I have for each loop for a table to display the new rows.
One row has a name in it so I want to give the td tag an Id of "CatName" + i where i is the iteration of the loop. For example if we are on the second iteration of the loop the id will be "CatName2". In the code posted below I have attempted to use the @ to call c# code but it only returns with a compilation error of :

`Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

```
@{
    int i = 0;
}
@foreach (CategoryVM category in Model.CategoryList)
{
    <tr>
        <td id="@{"CatName" + i.ToString()}"></td>
    </tr>
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation. And do not the answer in your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use parentheses ( ) rather than curly braces to evaluate a C# expression.

so change

```
<td id="@{"CatName" + i.ToString()}"></td>
```

to

```
<td id="@("CatName" + i.ToString())"></td>
```

The error is confirming that the content within `@{ }` should be a complete statement, not an expression.